# Sometimes ffmpeg crashes and the process still on task manager in windows

Tags: asp.net, iis, ffmpeg

I'm using **ffmpeg** for transcoding my videos on my servers.

Some times ffmpeg carshes in transode during, and that process stalled on task manager and it used ram,but not consumed cpu(it seems ffmpeg crashed).

1- Is there any solution for knowing that how can I manage this process on my servers?

2- Must be handle that from web server side or can I manage it from ffmpeg side?

I mean, ffmpeg has there any property for when transcoding take a long time,that stops.

Or Can I handle this from server side(iis recycling stops the process in run time transcoding, i don't want to use that, maybe I'm wrong, just help me).

**What is the best solution ?**

I used this code for example:

```
    ffmpeg -i kata.mp4 -filter_complex 
[0:v]drawtext=fontfile=OpenSansRegular.ttf:text=localhost/Parsa:fontcolor
=white:r=25:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.3:boxborderw=3:fontsize=15:x=15:y=(h-text_h-
15)[v];[v]split=4[s0][s1][s2][s3];[s0]scale=hd720[v0];[s1]scale=hd480[v1];
[s2]scale=nhd[v2];[s3]scale=cga[v3] -map [v0] -map [v1] -map [v2] -map [v3] -map
 a? -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee -g 48 -threads 0 "
[select='v\:0,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0]../video/720p/out.m3u8|
[select='v\:1,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0]../video/480p/out.m3u8|
[select='v\:2,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0]../video/360p/out.m3u8|
[select='v\:3,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0]../video/200p/out.m3u8"
```

Comment: How can the issue be duplicated? What is your ffmpeg command? Include the log/console output from ffmpeg.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard,I update my question.Can u help me?

Comment: Are there any errors when the crash occurs? Can you also include the console output? You can cut out any repeating lines in the middle if it is too big. Right now with the current information provided I can only recommend 1) that you use a recent ffmpeg (your version is currently unknown to me), and 2) simplify the command line to help narrow down what is causing the issue.